# Php function for last login is not working,

Tags: php, function, mysqli

Got a problem when creating a function/procedure to write the user's last login.

The query works standalone since I used to copy and paste this code into several pages, instead of that, I went for creating a whole new PHP file called functions.php where I store all of my functions.

The thing is that I created the function with the same code I had working before but still, I can't get it to work by just simply calling it.

Variable $connection has a `mysqli_connect()` function in order to create a connection with the database. This one is stored in an independent file.

```
function last_login(){
    $login = "UPDATE users SET last_log=NOW() WHERE user='".$user."'"; 
    mysqli_query($connection, $login);
  }

last_login();
```

I tried using

```
 return = mysqli_query($connection, $login);
```

to return a value into a normal `$variable` so I can output that on the other file, but nothing changed.

Also, to prove that there was a connection between these two files, created a new function containing an echo "lol world"; a single line, it indeed worked, so there I guess there is no problem there.

Comment: You're not passing `$user` into the function.

Comment: Also `return = mysqli_query` is not valid syntax, and the return if corrected would be a result object, not a value. Additionally, use parameterized queries.

Comment: Correct @user3783243, the value from the query must be *fetched*.

Comment: Nah.. update statements do not return a result set.. they only indicate "affected rows" (a number)

Comment: Even passing    $user into the functions I am still not able to get that field updated on the database...

Comment: Are you doing any error checking at all? Have you looked at the error logs? What is the column type of `last_log`?

Comment: Okay, got it to work. I also needed to pass the function another parameter in order to get it to firstly connect to the database: 

(I need serious help formatting this)

     function last_log(mysqli $connection, $user){
     $last_seen = "UPDATE users SET last_log =NOW() WHERE user='".$user."'";
     mysqli_query($connection, $login);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the variables for the connection and the user.

MySQL will store the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970. And calculate the difference. Also you can use `LOCALTIME()` function to get the current date and time as follows.

```
function last_login($connection, $user){
    $login = "UPDATE `users` SET `last_log` =  LOCALTIME() WHERE `user` ='$user'"; 
    mysqli_query($connection, $login);
  }

last_login($connection, $user);
```

Make sure the column last_log is timestamp and not date. You need to avoid SQL injection by using prepared statements. Also for more debugging of code use mysqli_error() function to know the exact error.

Comment: even that I get an output of 1970 January first in my code. Last_log is timestamp, yeah.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Yes I agreed @Jay Blanchard I just edited my answer.

Comment: The only thing you forgot about was SQL injection. Honestly, the OP is likely only really looking for a date, like `CURDATE()`

Comment: Yes for preventing SQL injection he can use prepared statements.

Comment: Then you should say that in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jay Blanchard for improving my Elaboration skills. I appreciate that.

Comment: What is the difference between `LOCALTIME()` and `NOW()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variables `$connection` and `$user` as arguments to your function.

```
// Define function which accepts 2 parameters
function last_login(mysqli $connection, string $user) {
    $stmt = $connection->prepare('UPDATE users SET last_log=NOW() WHERE user=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
    $stmt->execute();
}

// When calling the function pass the variables as arguments
last_login($connection, $user);
```

Pay attention to the fact that I used prepared statements. You should never inject variables into SQL queries, this could lead to broken code and leave you vulnerable to SQL injection.